# selecting items of a specific type from a list

Tags: types, filter, swift2

Given a set or array like `[1,2,3,"x"]` or `["1","2","3","x"]`, how might I best extract (using .filter perhaps) the integers (for example). In either of the examples above, I'm hoping to get the answer `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an hybrid array, I'd use `filter` and `is`:

```
let hybrid = [1,2,3,"x"]

let ints = hybrid.filter { $0 is Int }

print(ints)  // [1, 2, 3]
```

For an array of strings, I'd use `flatMap` and the `Int` initializer:

```
let strings = ["1","2","3","x"]

let ints = strings.flatMap { Int($0) }

print(ints)  // [1, 2, 3]
```